# how do i write this equation in 2D java code

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a problem to write this equation in java code.

I want to make it in a `for` loop and I also want to count the iteration.

```
k[1][1]=|f[1][1]-f[2][1]|+|f[1][1]-f[3][1]|;
k[2][1]=|f[2][1]-f[1][1]|+|f[2][1]-f[3][1]|;
k[3][1]=|f[3][1]-f[1][1]|+|f[3][1]-f[2][1]|;

public class deviation2 {
     public static void main(String [] args){
         double[][] k = new double[4][2];
         double[][] f = {{0.0,0.0},
                        {0.0,5.4,},
                        {0..0,4.0},
                        {0..0,1.5}};
        int m,i,j;

        for (j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
            m = 0;  

            for (i=1 ; i<3 ; i++) {               
                    m++;
            }
        }                                             
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`for (j = 1; j < 1; j++) {...}` can not work.

Comment: {......} this i want to put code for my equation but i don't know how to write it please help me!!!

Comment: Just `j = 1` and `j < 1` makes no sense.